# Bandpass of diffraction grating - exit slit width?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, diffraction, interferometry

I'm supposed to derive a relation for the range of wavelengths that's being transmitted by a spectrometer (bandpass) in terms of the dispersion, focal length and exit slit width.

Given grating is $100mm$ wide, slit separation $d=5.6\times 10^{-7} m$, focal length $f=1\space m$, exit slit width $w=100\mu m$ and spectrometer working in first order regime.

Then I'm supposed to find value of slit width that corresponds to a bandpass of theoretical resolving power of $\lambda \approx 500 nm$

**Attempt**

I found dispersion $\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda} = \frac{p}{d cos \theta} $ and resolving power $Np$.

Thus The amount of wavelengths contained in the dispersion is simply $\delta \theta \times \frac{d\lambda}{d\theta} $

But what is the angle of spread? Is it simply $\delta \theta = \frac{w}{f}$.

If so, then I find the bandpass $\Delta \lambda = \frac{w}{f} \times \frac{d}{p} = 5.6 \times 10^{-11} $.

Last part of the question doesn't make sense, as resolving power is only dependent on $N$.

Comment: What does $p$ represent?

Comment: the order of fringe